# How to disable the default context menu globally

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, contextmenu

The following code disables the default context menu of all the existing `TextField` added to `Scene`.

```
for (Node node : scene.getRoot().lookupAll("*")) {
  if (node instanceof TextField) {
    ((TextField)node).setContextMenu(new ContextMenu());
  }
}
```

But if you add another `TextField` to `Scene` later, its default context menu is not disabled.
If you run the code above each time you add `TextField`s, there would be no problem, but it is rather troublesome.

So are there any way to disable the default context menu of all the `TextField` (including ones added in the scene graph later)?

Comment: You can always make your own `TextField` implementation which does this upon creation, or use a factory method that does this for you. What is the usecase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`CONTEXT_MENU_REQUESTED` event](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ContextMenuEvent.html#CONTEXT_MENU_REQUESTED) can be consumed before it reaches the target `Node` by a event filter that is added to the `Scene` or to a `Parent` containing all the `TextField`s that should not open the context menu:

```
scene.addEventFilter(ContextMenuEvent.CONTEXT_MENU_REQUESTED, evt -> {
    if (checkTextField((Node) evt.getTarget())) {
        evt.consume();
    }
});
```

```
// check, if the node is part of a TextField
public static boolean checkTextField(Node node) {
    while (node != null) {
        if (node instanceof TextField) {
            return true;
        }
        node = node.getParent();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#contextmenu) to remove the context menu of `TextField` objects:

```
.text-field * .context-menu { 
    visibility: hidden;
}

.text-field * .context-menu > .scroll-arrow {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

The first style class hides `ContextMenu` itself. The second one hides the small arrow.